# How are lay people or litigants in person expected to engage with respect to the civil rules of procedure?

Tags: civil-procedure, pro-se, litigant-in-person

It's commonly said that there's a principle in the running of the courts of the UK that they are designed to accommodate and level the playing field within reason between professional barristers and litigants in person, and to make the process as accessible as possible and undaunting to the latter.

Yet the civil rules of procedure must take months of rigorous study to become familiar with which is prohibitive to most people who are not making a career in law.

How are litigants in person expected to behave with respect to not possibly knowing these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

Litigants in person are not expected to know all the rules.

The court and the opposition are expected to make all reasonable accommodations. The lawyers have a duty to the court and the administration of justice as well as their client.

For guidance see:

https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/topics/civil-litigation/litigants-in-person-guidelines-for-lawyers